# Windows fails to boot after setting "Switchable Graphics" to "Fixed Mode" on laptop

Tags: lag, switchable-graphics

I have a HP DV6 6140tx which has an i7, and AMD 6770M .

The games I played are sort of laggy (i.e 18-22fps on Fraps). I heard about switchable graphics and after searching a lot, I heard that changing switchable graphics to Fixed Mode in BIOS would do the trick.

But, whenever I change it to fixed mode, Windows doesn't boot and gives a Blue Screen of Death always.

I reinstalled drivers, reflashed BIOS, but nothing is helping. I am thinking of doing a fresh Windows install now.

Games are always laggy. (Skyrim, Prince of Persia -TWo thrones, NFS Carbon.. are the games I have played on it so far.)

What to do now?

Comment: You're playing these games on your Intel HD Graphics. Your AMD should be able to knock T2T and Carbon out of the park. It should also manage Skyrim at high/moderate settings with a fps around 40, if not more.

Answer (score 2):

HP [say](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c02731962#N49)

> An HP notebook PC with the switchable graphics feature always has two graphics adapter 
>   chipsets - a low power, integrated chipset and a high performance, discrete chipset.

...

> When using graphics-intense applications such as games, the discrete graphics processor enables high performance.

...

> Fixed Mode graphics require users to change the power state of the PC to enable the higher or lower power processor.

...

> **Using the Fixed Mode drivers on a notebook that supports Dynamic Mode will not work. Using Dynamic Mode drivers on a notebook that supports Fixed Mode switchable graphics will not work.**

It sounds to me like

- You were given bad advice.
- You should use the BIOS to change this setting back the way it was (dynamic).
- Maybe you can boot in safe mode (F8).

Comment: So can I use fixed mode? I am installing clean Windows now.

Comment: You should be able to used fixed mode if you have the right drivers. I doubt it will help speed up the game. Probably the biggest effect will be to shorten the run-time on batteries.

Comment: Well, I mostly use my laptop at home (plugged in , so shouldn't be a problem)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed mode will do the trick. I have a HP DV6-6115TX with an i5 processor and AMD 6490M graphics. I experienced the same problem (graphics lag) when I play Call of Duty MW3.

When I changed from dynamic mode to fixed mode perfomance increased a lot. If you are experiencing a problem with Windows not booting, keep the video card in fixed mode and then reset Windows to factory settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your [graphics card](http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-6770M.43955.0.html) is insufficient to play the games you have listed at high resolution and high quality graphics.  For example, with Skyrim, you can either have high resolution/high quality with low frame rates, or you can turn down the resolution and graphics settings to lower quality and have higher frame rates.  Even if you get the BIOS setting to work, you are unlikely to get any significant improvement in the games you list.  Your graphics card just isn't capable of doing much better.

Comment: Also all of my games detect Intel Mobile (HD) graphics and not the dGPU. Sorry , but I am a bit noob in this.