# How can I resolve screen tearing on my HP DV6 6140TX?

Tags: switchable-graphics, screen-tearing

I installed WIndows 7 fresh on my laptop, and now it boots in Fixed mode (Switchable graphics as set in BIOS)

But on booting, whenever dGPU (AMD 6770M) is selected, I get screen tearing.

And this screen tearing continues right from the time I boot.

What to do? Please help. Why can't I run fixed mode properly on my laptop.

Previous problem: [Windows fails to boot after setting "Switchable Graphics" to "Fixed Mode" on laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/456333/switchable-graphics-on-hp-dv6-6140tx)

Laptop:

- HP DV6 6140TX
- AMD 6770M